# Drawing half a parabola using pstricks in LaTeX

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

I am trying to create some typed notes about Dynamical Systems, and as part of this I wish to draw a stability diagram; this requires me to have a parabola of the form `$r = x^2$`, however, one half of the parabola needs to be dashed and the other half needs to be solid.

I am using `pstricks` with `dvips->ps2pdf` and my code currently looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \begin{pspicture}(5,5)
      \psline{->}(0,2.5)(5,2.5)
      \psline{->}(2.5,0)(2.5,5)
      \rput(2.75,4.8){$r$}
      \rput(4.8,2.25){$x$}
      \psparabola(4.08,0)(2.5,2.5)
   \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}
```

But I wish for one half of the parabola to be dashed and the other half to be solid. Is there an easy way to do this with `pstricks`?

Comment: instead of `dvips->ps2pdf` you can your document with `xelatex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pstricks and tikz solutions above use a parametric version of the parabola, plotting many points on a quadratic function.  In both cases you can use a single Bézier instead, using the recipe from my solution here: [How to draw rotated parabola in LaTeX with using tikz and Bezier curve?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159557/how-to-draw-rotated-parabola-in-latex-with-using-tikz-and-bezier-curve/159571#159571)

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}

   \begin{pspicture}(5,5)
      \psline{->}(0,2.5)(5,2.5)
      \psline{->}(2.5,0)(2.5,5)
      \rput(2.75,4.8){$r$}
      \rput(4.8,2.25){$x$}
 %     \psparabola(4.08,0)(2.5,2.5)
      \psbezier(2.5,2.5)(3.027,2.5)(3.553,1.666)(4.08,0)
      \psbezier[linestyle=dashed](2.5,2.5)(1.973,2.5)(1.447,1.666)(0.92,0)
   \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The control points for the first parabolic arc are from trisecting the intervals 2.5≤x≤4.08 and 0≤r≤2.5.  If you were going to do several of these, you could write some code to do these calculations.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to do it easily with `pst-plot`. You just have to plot the function `x²` twice, once with a solid line, one with a dashed line. Note it can perfectly be compiled with `pdflatex` if you load `auto-pst-pdf` *after* `pstricks`, provided pdflatex is launched with the `--enable-write18` switch (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX). Also, there exists a `\psaxes` command:

```
\documentclass[x11names, border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{ algebraic, arrowinset=0.2, arrowsize=2.5pt, arrowlength=1, linejoin=1}
\begin{pspicture*}(-4.9,-1)(5,5)
\psaxes[arrows=->, linecolor=SlateGray3, ticks=none, labels=none]{->}(0,0)(-5,0)(5,5)[$x$, -120][$r$, -140]
\uput[dl](0,0){$O$}
\psset{linewidth=1.2pt, linecolor=IndianRed3, plotpoints=200}
\psplot{0}{5}{x^2}
\psplot[linestyle=dashed, dash=6pt 3pt]{-5}{0}{x^2}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know `PSTricks` and think that `pgfplots` is state of the art
>   by now :). But if you need to use `PSTricks` then I will delete my
>   answer of course.
>
> On the other hand - a quick Google search revealed that probably
>   the `linestyle=dashed` option should do the trick. Just draw the parabola half 
>   by half.

There is a very powerful package called `pgfplots` ([CTAN link](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots)). It has many many features and maybe in the beginning the documentation is overwhelming.

If you are new to LaTeX I would recommend to draw it with another software and just put the picture in the document.

But if you have enough time then you should consider to learn more about `pgfplots` and the underlying `tikz/pgf` package ([CTAN link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)).

```
\documentclass{article}

% CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [
                title={Stable System},
                xlabel={$x$},
                ylabel={$r(x)$},
            ]
            %
            % right half
            \addplot
            [
                domain={0:5},
            ]{x^2};
            %
            % left half
            \addplot
            [
                domain={-5:0},
                dashed,
            ]{x^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that it is difficult to compete with `pgfplots` with `pstrick` `pst-plots` ...  In this pure TikZ can come closer:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz,preview]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
L/.style = {draw = blue!50!gray!30!white,-{Stealth[]}}
                    ]
\draw[L]    (-4, 0) -- (4,0) node[pos=1,below left] {$x$};    
\draw[L]    (0,-.1) node[below] {$0$} -- (0,5) node[below left] {$r(x)$}; 
% right half
\draw[red,thick,domain={-3:0},dashed]   plot (\x,{0.5*(\x)^2});
% left half
\draw[red,thick,domain={0:3}]           plot (\x,{0.5*(\x)^2});
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Since question was about`pstrick`, this answer is more for exercise :-) (and for showing alternative possibilities).

Comment: Frankly, I don't see in what respect pure TikZ comes closer than pgfplots or pst-plot. It mainly seems to be a matter of personal taste ;o)

Comment: Yes, it is personal opinion. In this particular -- simple -- case, the `pgfplots` is overwhelm with his rich features, which is not needed here. To draw present picture about one third code is needed for exclude automatic labeling etc. Maybe I'm wrong.